# How can I replace intraline tabs with spaces, maintaining alignment?

Tags: regex, vim, sed

I like to use spaces for indentation rather than tabs; replacing tabs at the beginning of a line is easy in `sed` or `vim`:

```
s/^I/    /g
```

But if there are tabs within a line (pretend the spaces are the width of the tab char):

```
'foo'^I ^I  => 'bar',
'bazzle'^I  => 'qux',
```

Each tab doesn't correspond to a set number of spaces to maintain the alignment.  Anyone have a sly idea of how to replaces those tab characters with spaces while keeping the correct alignment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Vim:

```
:retab
```

or, if you have tabs after spaces:

```
:retab!
```

Comment: Don't forget to set expandtab

Answer (score 14):

Under Linux and BSD, look up the expand and unexpand command line tools. expand will convert tabs to spaces, and unexpand performs the opposite operation. The simplest usage is:

```
expand filename
```

If you are like me, using 4 spaces for tabs, then:

```
expand -t 4 filename
```

By default, expand prints to the standard output and leave the original file in tact. To make in-place replacements, you have at least two choices:

```
$ cp filename backup
$ expand -t 4 filename > tempfile
$ mv tempfile filename
```

Or, you can invoke expand within vi:

```
$ vi filename
:%!expand -t 4
```

Comment: I wanted to do this without using another editor and `expand` works great.